# Maximum cost from a set of labels 1-n each with a weight vi

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem wherein I have a set of items with labels l1,l2,l3,....ln  each of which is associated with a weight vi.
n is "EVEN".

There are 2 people each of which will take turns to pick one item at a time. You can only pick an item with the largest or smallest remaining label.

All labels l1,l2,..ln are distinct but their weights vi may not be distinct.

I'm the 1st person to start. How do I ensure that I get the max weight after all the items are picked up?

This is the Q. Now this looks like a max-min problem to me with constraints that I can only pick largest or smallest label.

For example: if we have labels l5, l6, l7, l8 then the smallest remaining label is l5 while the largest remaining label is l8. So I can pick either l5 or l8.(their values may be anything).

Can someone help me understand as to how do I proceed with this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to ensure that you have the maximum total weight? You use the terms "value" and "weight". Are they the same thing? What does it mean, "largest or smallest remaining label?" Do you mean "label with the largest or smallest value?" You need to clarify your question. An example would help.

Comment: Yes weight and value mean the same. I updated the main post. Also,largest or smallest remaining label means "label" with largest/smallest index. ex: if I have labels l3, l4, l5 then l3 is the smallest remaining label. l5 is largest remaining label. Their weights may be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Say you create an *n X n* matrix, *P*, indicating the largest possible payoff for you. Specifically, *P<sub>i, j</sub>* indicates the largest payoff available to you if the sequence is between *i* and *j* (both inclusive).

By definition, the answer to your question is *P<sub>1, n</sub>*.

Start by setting any entry of the form *P<sub>i, i + d</sub>* for *d = 1*. These indicate sequences of length 2. Obviously, the payoff is the maximum of the two elements minus the minimum (recall that you are the player who starts).

Suppose you have filled out *P* for all entries of the form *P<sub>i, i + d'</sub>*, for some odd *d' > 1*, and now you wish to fill it up for all entries of the form *P<sub>i, i + d' + 2</sub>. There are four choices to check:

- you choose from the left and the adversary chooses from the left
- you choose from the left and the adversary chooses from the right
- you choose from the right and the adversary chooses from the left
- you choose from the right and the adversary chooses from the right

For each of these four options, you can calculate the result as you choice minus the adversary's choice plus results previously already filled out in *P*. Choose the largest of them.

The complexity is *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Comment: `In fact, you can just set as 0 any entry of the form Pi, i + d for an even d.` How?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Thanks for the comment. I see how the original text (now updated) might be misleading. You can set it to 0, as it won't play a role in the solution. The question is about the best payoff, assuming you're the first player, for an even-length sequence. For each interim problem, if you start by picking one, and the adversary picks another, you still have an even sequence. Odd-length sequences don't affect the solution, therefore.

Comment: In "Specifically, Pi, j indicates the largest payoff available to you if the sequence is between 1 and j", I think you mean "between i and j".  Also it doesn't help (though it also doesn't hurt) to maximise the *difference* in payoffs between the two players as you're currently doing -- the question asks for the maximum sum for player 1, but any solution that maximises the difference in payoffs will maximise the sum for player 1 (and vice versa) since the other player is forced to choose all remaining items.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Many thanks! Corrected the typo. Agree with your insightful other point as well.

Comment: Glad I could help :)